# what's the purpose of wado-rs vs Dicom Service Class Users/Providers

Tags: dicom

I am trying to figure out what's the difference between transferring dicom files with a (SCU/SCP) like pynetdicom3 vs using the wado api.

Both methods can be used for transferring dicom files. But I can't figure out what's the standard use case for each?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you can implement all common use cases with both approaches. The difference is rather in technology you are using and systems you want to interface with than in features supported by the one or the other approach.

The "traditional" TCP/IP based DICOM services have been developed since 1998. They are widely spread and widely supported by virtually all current systems in the field. From the nowadays perspective they may appear a bit clumsy and they have some built-in glitches (e.g. limitation to 127 presentation contexts). Still they are much more common than the web-based stuff.

Especially when it comes to communication use cases across different sites, it is hard to implement them with the TCP/IP based protocols.

The WADO services have been developed by the DICOM committee to adopt new technology and facilitate DICOM implementation for application based on web technology. They are quite new (in terms of the DICOM Standard ;-) ).
Having said that the major use case are web-based applications, I have not seen any traditional modalities supporting them yet, and I do not expect them to come up in the near future. This is because, you can *rely* on PACS supporting TCP/IP based DICOM but you would have to *hope* for WADO. 
There is a tendency for PACS systems to support WADO in *addition to* TCP/IP to facilitate integration of web viewers and mobile devices where an increasing number of applications only supports WADO.

So my very subjective advice would be:

- For an application that is designed for the usage within a hospital: Stick with TCP/IP based DICOM, since you can be quite sure that it will be supported by the systems you are going to interface with.
- If connectivity via internet is a major use case, or your application uses a lot of web technology, consider using WADO but investigate the support for WADO among the relevant systems you need to interface with. This probably depends on the domain your application is targeting.

Comment: I mostly came across WADO viewers only. I have never see any device or PACS that implement WADO for other services. OP should take your advice.

Comment: Agreed. I would expect WADO to be on the rise, especially since HL7 welcomes his new friend FHIR. WADO and FHIR are really a good framework to build web based medical applications, and the big players (google, MS, Apple) are pushing the web based standards. Maybe some day a new generation of developers will wonder why they should adopt such crazy stuff like DICOM TCP protocols and will push the WADO based stuff into areas where it is unthinkable today (modality <-> PACS). But this will probably take some years till this trend becomes significant.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the already very good answer by @kritzel_sw - WADO is only part of the picture. WADO is for retrieving images over the web. There's also STOW or STore Over the Web and QIDO or Query based on ID for DICOM Objects for storing new objects to PACS and querying the PACS respectively.

I think we will see it more and more in the future and not only for web based DICOM viewers, but also normal DICOM communications between the systems. It's especially useful for the cases where one of the systems is not DICOM aware and the developers are also not experienced in DICOM.

Consider a use case from my own experience. We want doctors to be able to upload photographs of skin conditions of their patients and send these photos to our PACS. It's much easier and probably cheaper to commision some developer to do it with STOW, where the specification is basically "take the JPG photo uploaded by the user, add necessary metadata in JSON format according to spec and send it all to this address with an HTTP POST request" rather than "convert uploaded JPG files to valid DICOM objects with the necessary metadata, transfer syntax etc and implement a C-STORE SCU to send it to our PACS". For the first job you can get any decent developer experienced in web dev, for the second you need to find someone who already knows what DICOM is with all its quirks or pay someone a lot to learn it.

That's why I love all these new web-based DICOM options and see great future for those.